# Videos are preventing Whatsapp Notifications on iPhone even after they have stopped

Tags: iphone, ios, video, notifications

On an iPhone 7. If I watch a video on netflix (or youtube) all Whatsapp notifications (not Facebook messenger, which works as expected) are stopped until I open whatsapp, when I get them all.   It's exactly as if opening any sort of full screen video disables push notifications for that particular app.

What can cause this and how can I fix it.  Have done the normal reboots and reinstalls...

Versions and so on:

- iPhone 7
- iOS 14.8.1
- Whatsapp version 2.22.14.74 (most recent according to App Store)
- Netflix version 14.46.0 (also most recent version)

Comment: Which version of iOS, wich version of the Whatsapp, Netflix, Youtube app? Does this happen when you play a youtube video in Safari? On a side note: I am not suprised that e.g. Netflix will some how not pass thru notifications, it would have some strange impact when casting to a TV etc.

Comment: Have you checked if _Background App Refresh_ is activated for Whatsapp? Additionally check the notification settings in Whatsapptap -  you'll find a variety of options. These are broken into two major headers: Message notifications and Group notifications. The Message settings are for one-on-one conversations, while Group is for group chats. Do you have an Apple watch?

Comment: check as well as _Settings>Notifications>Show Preview_ then select e.g WA from the list of apps and press the indicator "Allow Notifications".

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is allow whatsapp to **run in background**

Many whatsapp users experienced this problem

**This video help me a lot..**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=741yq5GCNJ8